# Controlling output file of a java jar using command line

Tags: java, python, jar, terminal

I am using a `.jar` file, but unfortunatley as a black box, i.e. I do not know what exactly is in there nor how it all works.

I am sending commands to the Mac terminal from a Python script. I enter the following command:

```
java -jar jarfile.jar req_data /abs_path/to/required/data input path/to_my_/input/file.txt
```

This does what I need: analyses input using the 'black box' and creates and new file with analysis output. This new file is created in the folder where `jarfile.jar` is located.

I want to have this file put somewhere else upon creation.

I have tried using the `>` operator, specifying a path, e.g.:

```
java -jar jarfile.jar req_data /abs_path/to/required/data input path/to_my_/input/file.txt > /output/path/
```

this created *a* file in my desired location, but it was simply the message from Terminal, saying "The operation was carried out successfully" - the analysis results file was created in the same folder as before.
I tried `%*>` too, but it threw an error.

As a poor workaround I now have a function, which retrospectively finds and moves all the newly created files (analysis output) to my desired folder.

Is there a way to control the output files with the command line *within* the original command?  Or is it something that is specified somewhere in my `jar` file? My problem is that editing it is not allowed.

Comment: What happens when you call the jar with an absolute path from a different working directory ? Have you decompiled the jar ? Perhaps it supports command line parameters or contains classes you can call from your own Java code easily.

Comment: If I call it from a different directory with an absolute path, the file is still created where the jar file itself is. I have found that I can run -help on the jar file, which gives me some other options (specific to the black-box magic), but nothing for directing the output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to python. However, I may suggest to try few things, if they can work for you. Apology me, if does not work! I believe that you have already done the following step:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'Blender.jar'])
```

Like, if you have a properly configured jar path, then can run jar directly.

Secondly, look at the `cwd` parameter (is used for executable). Include a `cwd` param as x

```
def run_command(command, **x):
    with subprocess.Popen(command,...., **x) as p:
```

for `run_command` specify the path of either the working directory (possibly it should be) or the full system path. I'm not sure, just try both.

for outputline in `run_command(r'java -jar jarfilepath', cwd=r'workingdirpath',                 universal_newlines=True):`

```
print(outputline, end='')
```

Alternatively, you can try to run command from the directory in which you wish to store output file. Try: run the popen as

```
subprocess.Popen(r'directory of running command', cwd=r'workingdir')
```

where workingdir could be your current directory path.

If it does not work, try without `r'`. If still does not work, try doubling slash in the path like (`C:\\ abc\\def`)

Comment: Yes I use the subprocess module. If I try using any of your extra commands above, it seems the jar file is trying to use them, as it throws me an error, saying for example "Unrecognised command - wrong spelling or case?: cwd=/my/path" - with and without `r'`. It then points me to its own help.
I am starting to think the output path is specified in the .jar somewhere and must be changed there.